# Unable to run app using Ionic (permission denied)

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to run the app with Ionic (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).

When I try to do

```
ionic platform add android
```

I get the following error:

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions

        Adding android project...

            Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
            Path: platforms/android
            Package: com.ionicframework.starter
            Name: ...
            Android target: android-21
        Copying template files...
        Project successfully created.
        Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/.../.../.../plugins/android.json'
            at Error (native)
            at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
            at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1156:15)
            at PlatformJson.save (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/PlatformJson.js:40:8)
            at PlatformMunger_save_all [as save_all] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:83:23)
            at Object.exports.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/config-changes.js:59:12)
            at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:69:20)
            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:108:21
            at Array.map (native)
            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:73:40
```

Comment: Can you please check the file permissions of the mentioned file `android.json`?

Comment: How do I check permission for a specific file?

Comment: Type `ls -l` followed by the path to your file.

Comment: can you please try it with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't have to use sudo - as suggested in the accepted answer - for adding a new platform or for any other command to set up Ionic apart from `npm install`.

That it solves your problem means that you probably have used sudo for some other setup step before where it's not necessary. Check the file permissions and file owner of the file mentioned in the error message. If it belongs to *root*, I would recommend to repeat your Ionic setup and to pay attention to use only "normal" user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need administrator privileges

Try

> sudo ionic platform add android